# How to show artifacts from downstream jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I have one Jenkins job with lots of parameters, and another which just starts a configured instance of the first job. When I open the view of the upstream job, I would like to be able to access the artifacts the downstream job created. How can I achieve this? Currently I have to click on the downstream job to access my artifacts, the upstream job shows nothing.